# JavaPOET - only classes have super classes, not INTERFACE

Tags: java, spring-boot, code-generation, javapoet

I am trying to generate code for JPA repository below using JavaPOET library but
i am getting **"only classes have super classes, not INTERFACE"** error.

```
@Repository 
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> { 
}
```

Here is the JavaPOET code i tried..

```
TypeSpec userRepository = TypeSpec.interfaceBuilder("UserRepository")
                .addAnnotation(Repository.class)
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                .superclass(ParameterizedTypeName.get(ClassName.get(PagingAndSortingRepository.class),  
                                                      ClassName.get(User.class),
                                                      ClassName.get(Long.class)))
                .build();
```

Any solution/best practice for generating interface extending a class?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is rather clear :

> "only classes have super classes, not INTERFACE" error.

`TypeSpec.Builder.superclass()` indeed allows to specify only classes.
To specify an interface, use `TypeSpec.Builder.addSuperinterface()`.

It would give :

```
TypeSpec userRepository = TypeSpec.interfaceBuilder("UserRepository")
                .addAnnotation(Repository.class)
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                .addSuperinterface(ParameterizedTypeName.get(ClassName.get(PagingAndSortingRepository.class),  
                                                      ClassName.get(User.class),
                                                      ClassName.get(Long.class)))
                .build();
```

It should generate this code:

```
@org.springframework.data.repository.Repository
public interface UserRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository<User, java.lang.Long> {
}
```

You can find complete examples in the unit tests of the JavaPOET project.
See the [git](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/master/src/test/java/com/squareup/javapoet/TypeSpecTest.java) .

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.. Could you also suggest me a way for compiling this generated code at runtime so that it can work without redeploy. As far as i know JavaPOET doesnt have this capability right? If you want me to post another question for this. Thats ok.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry, I don't know a lot this lib. This issue may maybe interest you : https://github.com/square/javapoet/pull/396.